# How to avoid browser automatically inducing changes to the DOM

Tags: html, dom

Let's say I have some html codes like this

```
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th role="col">Candidate</th>
            <th role="col">Party</th>
            <th role="col">Total receipts</th>
            <th role="col">Total disbursements</th>
            <th role="col">Cash on hand</th>
            <th role="col">Source reports</th>
          </thead>
        </table>
```

If I try opening this html file with a browser, it would automatically add a `<tr>` tag wrapping the `<th>` tags, and now the DOM would be like this

```
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th role="col">Candidate</th>
              <th role="col">Party</th>
              <th role="col">Total receipts</th>
              <th role="col">Total disbursements</th>
              <th role="col">Cash on hand</th>
              <th role="col">Source reports</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
```

How do I prevent this browser's behavior? I want it to open the file exactly as the source code is, even if it's broken codes.

Comment: This isn't valid HTML. You told it it's HTML (by opening it as an HTML page), so it will make its best to render it as such. What you want it to do is to open it as something else than HTML, and the browser has no way of knowing what this "something else" is. This exact markup could be parsed to DOM as XML for instance, but you'd need to let the browser know that it should open it as XML, and you wouldn't have an HTMLTableElement anymore, nor anything from an HTML page..

Comment: Then, is there a way I can let browsers somehow notify me this isn't valid HTML before they try rendering the page by injecting tags to DOM

Comment: No, this the job of a validator not of a browser. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea